# Why is my check() function not working in the JavaScript? Please someone check my code

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I designed a little login page and my function for checking isn't working properly.

I created div elements and a function to check it by Id in the Javascript. But It isn't working properly It is saying "Invalid username or password" when the function is supposed to check the value in the "user and pass"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<header id="header">Please Login Here</header>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title id="title">Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div id="user">
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div id="pass">
        <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        if (document.getElementById("user") == "Guy" && (document.getElementById("pass")) == "123") {
            alert("Welcome!")
        } else {
            alert("Invalid username or password!")
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="login">
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="check()">Login!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The expected result was "Welcome!" in an alert box when the correct things are entered:
username: Guy
password: 123

Comment: Just put id attribute on inputs like `        <input id='user' type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">`

Comment: @farvilain - OP used this ID for `<div>` element.

Comment: so what? he can change, right?

Comment: Be aware that you can never use such code for any production environment. Password checking **must** be done on the server, never put the credentials in the frontend code., neither HTML nor JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the element dev with id user and the element dev with id pass, then verify the user name and password
You should read the value of user textbox and password textbox then verify that way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<header id="header">Please Login Here</header>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title id="title">Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" Id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
 debugger;
        if (document.getElementById("user").value == "Guy" && (document.getElementById("pass").value) == "123") {
            alert("Welcome!")
        } else {
            alert("Invalid username or password!")
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="login">
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="check()">Login!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.value` on the input elements - so use `querySelector`. Also check your parenthesis nesting:

```js
function check() {
  if (document.querySelector("#user > input").value == "Guy" && document.querySelector("#pass > input").value == "123") {
    alert("Welcome!")
  } else {
    alert("Invalid username or password!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="user">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
</div>

<div id="pass">
  <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div id="login">
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="check()">Login!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a big clean

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script>
            function check() {
                var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
                var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                if ( user == "Guy" && pass == "123") {
                    alert("Welcome!")
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid username or password!")
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>Please Login Here</header>
        <form>
            <input id="user" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" onclick="check()">Login!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```